# How fast can you expend your Psionic Focus if you have Deep Focus feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics

> Deep Focus [Psionic] Prerequisite: Psionic Body, Autohypnosis 4 ranks.
>
> Benefit: You can psionically focus your subconscious in the same
>   manner in which you gain psionic focus normally. At any time when you
>   need to expend your psionic focus, you can expend your subconscious’s
>   psionic focus instead. At any time when you need to maintain psionic
>   focus for an effect, you can use your subconscious’s psionic focus
>   instead. Psionically focusing your subconscious works just like
>   focusing your conscious mind.
>
> Special: You cannot benefit from both Psicrystal Containment and Deep
>   Focus at the same time. If you have both feats, you may only have your
>   psicrystal or your subconscious maintaining psionic focus at any given
>   time.

I assume focusing both would take full action. Now with feats that require expulsion of Pionic Focus and multiple attacks normally or with Rapid Shot or Two Weapon Fighting feats; can you expend both foci on multiple attacks or is restricted to once per turn/round?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent action cost or rate limit on expending psionic focus; you may do so as often as you have a reason to do so so long as you have focus to expend. You can even expend two foci while manifesting a single power, to apply two metapsionic feats to it. Likewise, you could apply the “on expend” feature of two psionic feats to a single attack. Expending focus on subsequent attacks is also valid.

By the way, focusing *either* requires a full-round actions; focusing both requires two full-round actions. You could do it in one turn using Psionic Meditation, which makes each psionic focus take a move action. Also, for the record, Psicrystal Containment is much better than Deep Body (solely because Psicrystal Affinity is a good feat, while Psionic Body is garbage).

Comment: But wouldn't Psionic Meditation make gain focus as a move action there in focusing twice would be a single full action? Sorry I forgot to mention that in this post.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver That’s... what I said? I said you could focus both in a single turn by using two move actions with Psionic Meditation.

Comment: Sorry missed that part I was reading it during actual game didn't see the rest.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Psionic Body becomes more valuable in E6/E7/E8 games (though it often gets capped there)